# Imagens e css não carregam na pagina quando executo pelo jar

Tags: java, css, spring-boot, thymeleaf, jar

Olá, vi que já tiveram perguntas parecidas com a minha porem não respondeu minha duvida.
Estou desenvolvendo uma API que vai num banco de dados, pega os dados e devolve um relatório em pdf usando thymeleaf e flying saucer. Quando eu executo  o programa pela IDE( que no caso é o spring boot) tudo funciona normalmente. Porém quando executo pelo jar, as imagens não aparecem e nem o css. Já verifiquei dentro do jar e tantos minhas imagens quanto o css estão dentro dele. As dependências do flying Saucer(que é quem adiciona as imagens e o css) tbm estão. Aqui vão os detalhes, primeiro a estrutura do meu projeto:

[image: ![Estrutura do projeto]

Abaixo segue o código onde esta a engine de renderização, uso Thymeleaf, Jtidy e Flying Sauce para gerar um pdf:

```
@Service
public class GeneratePdfService {

    private static final String OUTPUT_FILE = "report.pdf";
    private static final String UTF_8 = "UTF-8";

    @Autowired
    private AgfService service;

    @Autowired
    private DateUteisComponent dataUtil;

    public OutputStream generatePdf(Object dataReport, String template) throws Exception {

        String renderedHtmlContent = generateHtml(dataReport, template);
        String xHtml = convertToXhtml(renderedHtmlContent);

        ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
        renderer.getFontResolver().addFont("template/Code39.ttf", IDENTITY_H, EMBEDDED);

        String baseUrl = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("src", "main", "resources").toUri().toURL().toString();
        renderer.setDocumentFromString(xHtml, baseUrl);
        renderer.layout();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        renderer.createPDF(outputStream);
        outputStream.close();
        return outputStream;
    }

    private String convertToXhtml(String html) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        Tidy tidy = new Tidy();
        tidy.setInputEncoding(UTF_8);
        tidy.setOutputEncoding(UTF_8);
        tidy.setXHTML(true);
        ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes(UTF_8));
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        tidy.parseDOM(inputStream, outputStream);
        return outputStream.toString(UTF_8);
    }

    public String generateHtml(Object dataReport, String template) {
        ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode(HTML);
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding(UTF_8);

        TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

        Date instanteAtual = new Date();
        String[] instanteAtualF = dataUtil.formatDateInstant(instanteAtual);

        Context context = new Context();
        context.setVariable("instante", instanteAtualF);
        context.setVariable("data", dataReport);

        String renderedHtmlContent = templateEngine.process(template, context);

        return renderedHtmlContent;
    }
```

Essa classe esta como um service e a classe que ultiliza esse serviço tbm é um serviço como segue abaixo:

```
public OutputStream gerarRelatorioPrePostagemPorEstadoPdf(String estado) throws Exception {
    List<PrePostagemBean> prePostagensBeans = generateDataForReportForUf(estado);
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = (ByteArrayOutputStream) this.generatePdfService.generatePdf(prePostagensBeans, "template/templateE");
    this.sendConfirmationHtmlEmail(outputStream.toByteArray());
    return outputStream;
}
```

Por ultimo esse serviço é chamado a partir de um controlador rest:

```
@GetMapping(value = "agfs/{estado}/pdf", produces = "application/pdf")
public ResponseEntity<?> prepostReportEstadoPdf(@PathVariable("estado") String estado) throws Exception {
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = (ByteArrayOutputStream) this.agfService.gerarRelatorioPrePostagemPorEstadoPdf(estado);
    byte[] content = os.toByteArray();
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF);
    ResponseEntity<byte[]> response = new ResponseEntity<byte[]>(content, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    return response;
}
```

O objetivo e devolver na tela um pdf com o relatório.
O problema é que quando eu rodo o projeto a partir do spring boot, tudo funciona perfeitamente e tenho a resposta como segue abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porem quando eu faço e deploy(através do comando mvn clean install) e coloco o jar em uma pasta qualquer da minha maquina e subo aplicação por esse jar, o css e as imagens não aparecem e fico com a seguinte resposta em HTML puro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O mais estranho é que quando eu executo o jar sem mover ele, ou seja, dentro da pasta target gerada na própria estrutura do maven o css e a imagem aparecem. Porém como disse antes, quando eu movo esse jar e executo ele em outro ambiente qualquer o css e a imagem são perdidos.

Abaixo segue me HTML tbm pra ajudar:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="static/css/style.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/jquery.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="static/css/bootstrap.css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/bootstrap.js" ></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class='header' th:include="template/header::header"></div>


    <h1 class="tit-relatorio">Relatorio Agfs x Pre Postagem</h1>

    <div class="periodo">Período: [[${data[0].dataInicio}]] até [[${data[0].dataFim}]]</div>

    <div class="periodo">Estado: [[${data[0].empresa.uf}]] </div>

    <div class="emitido">Relatório emitido em [[${instante[0]}]] as [[${instante[1]}]]</div>

    <hr></hr>

    <div class="div-table table-sm p-3" style="max-width:600px">
        <table class="table table-striped mb-3">
            <thead class="thead-dark">
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Agf:</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fizeram Pré-Postagem:</th>
                    <th scope="col">Não fizeram Pré-Postagem:</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tr th:each="data : ${data}">
                <td scope="row" th:text="${data.empresa.empresa}">nome</td>
                <td th:text="${data.qtdPrePost}">prePost</td>
                <td th:text="${data.qtdNoPrePost}">noPrePost</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>

    <div class="mt-1">
        <div><i>A segunda coluna indica a quantidade de clientes ativos que fizeram pré-postagem</i></div>
        <div><i>A terceira coluna indica a qauntidade de clientes ativos que não fizeram pré-postagem</i></div>
    </div>


    <div class='footer' th:include="template/footer::footer"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Tentei formular minha pergunta da melhor maneira possível, porem qualquer duvida ou critica só mandar que eu explico ou reformulo a pergunta. Preciso muito achar a solução pra esse problema pois tenho prazo

Comment: Ola @Satyan, bem vindo ao SOpt, antes de começar de uma olhada em nosso [Tour]. Sobre sua pergunta, talvez seja necessário você adicionar mais informações sobre seu projeto, para a comunidade entender melhor seu problema e assim te ajudar a conseguir uma solução. =D

Comment: Ok, vou ler sim e refazer, sou novo por aqui, valeu!

Comment: @IcaroMartins tentei melhorar minha pergunta e deixar nos padrões do site, qualquer critica só falar que eu ajeito

Answer (score 2):

Opa, achei o problema, esta na parte:

```
String baseUrl = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("src", "main", "resources").toUri().toURL().toString();
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(xHtml, baseUrl);
```

Pois quando estou executando pelo jar o caminho não é mesmo, então tive que definir um caminho pra PROD e outro pra DEV, pra pPROD ficou da seguinte maneira:

```
String baseUrl = "jar:file:" + System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/joaquina.reports.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/";
```